# Mapbox: Apply function to current layer

Tags: javascript, leaflet, mapbox

I created a dropdown that will change the colors of various parts of a JSON map depending on the value of the category selected. It is very similar to this [map](https://www.mapbox.com/mapbox.js/example/v1.0.0/choropleth-joined-data-multiple-variables/).

However, this only works when there is one JSON layer (the example has it colored on the state level). However, right now I have 2 JSON layers, one that renders the map on the zip and county level and they're set up as so:

```
var baseMaps = {
  "US" : usmap,
};

var overlayMap = {
  "Counties" : layer1,
  "Zip Codes" : layer2,
};

L.control.layers(baseMaps, overlayMap).addTo(map);
```

};

How do I make the following logic in JS to be something like: For whatever layer that is chosen in `overlay`, apply this `color` function it? I'd like to avoid repeating the function over and over again for each layer.

Thanks!